# o365 rest api contact, no property fax?

Tags: field, contacts, fax, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I import some contacts in O365 with the API REST. My code works good. I update all fields. But in my case, the last field to import is the BusinessFax Number. And I don't found this field! In the O365 Web app, or in Outlook, I look some fields for fax numbers. But no in the documentation of rest api o365 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesContact

and no in data definition type : https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata

If I test some properties in my Json file : Fax, FaxNumber, BusinessFax,... I get an error 400, bad request :(

It's amaziiiiiiiing... So, how to import a fax number in a contact ??? lol

nico

Answer (score 1):

This property hasn’t supported by the Office 365 REST API yet. As a workaround, we can get this property through the Exchange Web service. And here is an code sample to retrieve the fax phone number for your reference:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("{EmailAddress}", "{Password}");

    service.TraceEnabled = true;
    service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

    service.AutodiscoverUrl("{EmailAddress}", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

    Folder contacts = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);
    SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactSchema.GivenName, "user1"));
    ItemView view = new ItemView(1);


    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults =service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts,sf, view);

    foreach (Item item in findResults)
    {
        if (item is Contact)
        {
            Contact contact = item as Contact;
            Console.WriteLine(contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessFax]);
        }
    }

}


private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{
    // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
    bool result = false;

    Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

    // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
    // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
    // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
    if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can refer to this property through link below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact_properties(v=exchg.80).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact.phonenumbers(v=exchg.80).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.phonenumberkey(v=exchg.80).aspx

And you may also interested with authentication with Exchange web service, here are the links for your reference:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2015/05/11/ews-authentication-issues.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook REST API now supports Extended Properties in the beta endpoint, which you can use to get/set a property not returned on the item's default shape. If you want to get Contacts with their BusinessFax value, it's as easy as doing a GET against:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Me/Contacts?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A24')
```

(The hex value is the MAPI property tag value. For BusinessFax, it's 0x3A24) You can also use PATCH to update the business fax number for a given contact. Here's what the JSON payload would look like:

```
{
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties" : 
  [
    {
      "PropertyId" : "String 0x3A24",
      "Value" : "123-456-7890"
    }
  ]
}
```

Again, this is currently only supported in the beta endpoint, which we don't recommend using for any production code, as there are often breaking changes.

[Reference For Extended Properties in REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations)